# assets_host in carrierwave config

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave

Since I am currently using nginx to serve public/uploads only in subdomain assets, and also I am using the client side template(eco) to render the image (so I cannot use image_tag or image_url helper method provided by rails), I need to set the model.image_url (which provided by carrierwave) to return url with same domain.

Here is what I had tried: (in config/initializer/carrierwave.rb)

```
    CarrierWave.configuration do |config|
            config.assets_host = "http://assets.lvh.me:3000"
    end
```

But when I try this setting then the rails popup an error message:

```
    undefined method `assets_host=' for CarrierWave::Uploader::Base:Class (NoMethodError)
```

Since the README of carrierwave has this description of setting but only in fog section, so I'm wondering that is this function only work while using fog? Or did I miss anything?

Thanks for help

Answer (score 7, accepted):

should use `asset_host` ( version > 0.7.0)

see chnage commit on github
https://github.com/jnicklas/carrierwave/commit/7046c93d6b23cffef9f171a5f7f0dd14267a7057#lib/carrierwave/uploader/configuration.rb

```
CarrierWave.configuration do |config|
  config.asset_host = "http://assets.lvh.me:3000"
end
```

Answer (score 1):

In later versions this changed to

```
CarrierWave.configure do |config|
  ...
end
```